# Towers of Hanoi

Tags: c++, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I am working on an exercise in a book which asks us to solve the Towers of Hanoi problem using recursive methods. I have come to a solution, but from what I gather after browsing the Internet when done is that my solution may not be correct. Does anyone know a better/different way to solve the problem? And does anyone have nay suggestions for improvements. (Btw, the out put is correct. It is only supposed to tell from which tower to another pegs are moving, not specifically which pegs)

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

static int counter = 0;

void ToH(int dskToMv, int cLocation, int tmpLocation, int fLocation)
{
if (dskToMv == 0);
else
{
    if (dskToMv%2!=0)
    {
        cout << cLocation << "->" << tmpLocation << endl;
        cout << cLocation << "->" << fLocation << endl;
        cout << tmpLocation << "->" << fLocation << endl;
        ToH(dskToMv-1, cLocation, fLocation, tmpLocation);
    }
    else if (dskToMv%2==0)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter%2==0)
            cout << fLocation << "->" << cLocation << endl;
        else
            cout << cLocation << "->" << fLocation << endl;
        ToH(dskToMv-1, tmpLocation, cLocation, fLocation);
    }
}
}

int main()
{
int x, j;
cout << "Enter number of disks: ";
cin >> x;
j = pow(2.0, x-1)-1;
if (x%2==0)
    ToH(j, 1, 2, 3);
else
    ToH(j, 1, 3, 2);
return 0;
}
```

Is this method qualified as recursion?

Comment: For variants of the hanoi tower puzzle check the book: Concrete Mathematics - A Foundation for Computer Science.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question: yes, that is qualified as recursion. Any time a function calls itself, it is recursion.

With that being said, your code can be trimmed down substantially:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void ToH(int dskToMv, int cLocation, int tmpLocation, int fLocation)
{
    if( dskToMv != 0 ) 
    {
        ToH( dskToMv-1, cLocation, fLocation, tmpLocation );
        cout << cLocation << "->" << fLocation << endl;
        ToH( dskToMv-1, tmpLocation, cLocation, fLocation );
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Enter number of disks: ";
    cin >> x;
    ToH(x, 1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh. Thanks! I figured that my code was kinda clumsy, but I did not know that it could be trimmed that much! :D

Comment: sidenote: from this, you can also quickly get the number of steps needed: `H(n) = 2*H(n-1) + 1`. now if you add both side 1, you get the nice `H(n) + 1 = 2(H(n-1) + 1)` recursive equation and since `H(1) = 1` you get `H(n) = 2^n - 1`

Comment: @Stargazer Working on it! It seems quite obvious now that you posted the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Just to be picky, more than just a function calling itself, recursion has to have a defined end case.  In this code it is: `if( dskToMv != 0 )`.  Either way, it the code is still recursive.

Comment: @Robert Gowland, an end point is necessary for well formed recursion, but is infinite recursion still considered a type of recursion? :-P. Not that it really matters :)

Comment: @alirezasanaee, I assure you that there are no extra movements. The solution is simple recursion and is extensively documented online. Please attempt to learn how it works before you make the claim that there is something wrong.

Comment: @Stargazer712 I know what you mean but this answer is in my mind( For 3 disk ) : **1->2 1->2 1->3 2->3 2->3** just that , NOT 7 STEP , and if I bothered you by my question I really apologize about that . thanks :)

Comment: @alirezasanaee, that sequence is illegal. You are not allowed to put a larger disk on a smaller disk, therefore the sequence 1->2, 1->2 is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest if you look at the problem recursively:

To move N discs from A to B (using C):

1. if (N > 1) move N-1 discs from A to C (using B)
2. move one disc from A to B
3. if (N > 1) move N-1 discs from C to B (using A)

For any given call, whichever peg is *not* the source or the destination is the ancillary.

To answer your actual question: yes, your solution appears to be recursive, though a bit more complex than really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Every recursion method has 3 steps

1) A check condition
2) Return value when check condition is satisfied.
3) A call to method itself

@Stargazer712 solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void towers(int, char, char, char);

void towers(int num, char frompeg, char topeg, char auxpeg)
{
    if (num == 1)
    {

        cout<<"\n Move disk 1 from peg "<<frompeg<<" to peg "<<topeg<<endl;

        return;
    }

    towers(num - 1, frompeg, auxpeg, topeg);

    cout<<"\n Move disk "<<num<<" from peg "<<frompeg<<" to peg "   <<topeg<<endl;

    towers(num - 1, auxpeg, topeg, frompeg);
}

int main()
{
    int num;

    cout<<"Enter the number of disks : ";

    cin>>num;

    cout<<"The sequence of moves involved in the Tower of Hanoi are :\n"<<endl;

    towers(num, 'A', 'C', 'B');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i use functions that are called recursive functions, in this code, function calling itself again and again... that's how the whole program is running

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution for tower of hanoi.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void move(vector<int>& frompeg, vector<int>& topeg) {
    topeg.push_back(frompeg.back());
    frompeg.pop_back();
}

void hanoi(vector<int>& frompeg, vector<int>& topeg, vector<int>& auxpeg, 
int num_disks) {
    if (num_disks == 1) {
        move(frompeg, topeg);
    }
    else {
        hanoi(frompeg, auxpeg, topeg, num_disks - 1);
        move(frompeg, topeg);
        hanoi(auxpeg, topeg, frompeg, num_disks - 1);
    }
}

void printpeg(vector<int> a, vector<int> b, vector<int> c) {
    cout << "a: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "b: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
        cout << b[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "c: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
        cout << c[i] << " ";
    }

}

int main() {

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a,b,c;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a.push_back(n - i);
    }
    cout << "befor: " << endl;
    printpeg(a, b, c);
    hanoi(a, b, c, n);
    cout << "after: " << endl;
    printpeg(a, b, c);
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.